# WMI Can't Obtain ASP.NET 4.0 Application Performance Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wmi, performancecounter

I was trying to get performance counter data for one of my ASP.NET 4.0 website through WMI. I was able find the instance for my website under the counter "ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319" through perfmon just fine. But, I wasn't able to find that instance through WMI (using wbemtest) under class Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETAppsv4030319. In fact, the only instance I see under that class is `__Total__`. I don't think it is a permission issue since I am using an admin account, and I was accessing the WMI locally. Also, I was able to see the instances for my ASP.NET 2.0 websites just fine through WMI. I did try to reload/restart the WMI, and that didn't really help either. Do you know what might be causing this problem?